# jquery.post does not work with object literal

Tags: jquery, slim

Similarly to the [$.post API](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) I do:

```
$.post('http://...', POST_BODY, function(data) {...});

POST_BODY                            GIVES ME
{name:'test'}                        Empty response
{'name':'test'}                      Empty response
{"name":"test"}                      Empty response
'{"name":"test"}'                    stdClass Object([name] => test)
JSON.stringify({"name":"test"})      stdClass Object([name] => test)
```

e.g.

```
$.post('http://...', {name:'test'}, function(data) {...});
```

My php rest function:

```
function postContact(...) {
    $request = Slim::getInstance()->request();
    $body= json_decode($request->getBody());
    print_r($body);
}
```

Why can't I use object literal as described in jQuery API? Is it my server-side or client-side which is wrong?

Comment: How do you define the object?

Comment: edited with "e.g. ..." to make it clearer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You understood this wrong. Passing an object literal will cause jQuery to take each property of the object as a key and turn all values into strings and transform this into post parameters, which have the form `key1=val1&key2=val2`. And of course that's no JSON and thus `json_decode` fails silently.

Comment: Yes, thank you. My mistake, I assumed that the second parameter would get converted to JSON. It's pretty clear in the docs that it is only POST data...

Answer (score 3):

jQuery doesn't actually post an "object literal" to your PHP script.  It's converted to a query string, and sent as POST data, just like if you were to post a form normally.

You don't need to `json_decode` anything, you just need to read the `$_POST` array, and get its values.

Your last 2 examples work, because you are sending a JSON string as the POST body, but your other examples send standard query strings as the POST body.